# Send push notification in parse cloud code after matching two different classes

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to send a push notification after a user's status update has changed (status update is managed in the submission class in parse core data) but I'm using cloud code to match users phone numbers in the User and submission classes so that the push notification only targets the one specific user.

```
    Parse.Cloud.afterSave("submission", function(request) {
 var statusText = request.object.get('status');
 var phoneNumber = request.object.get('Phone');

   Parse.Cloud.afterSave("User", function(request) {
 var userPhone = request.object.get('Phone');
 var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.submission);

   pushQuery.matchesQuery(userPhone, phoneNumber);
  Parse.Push.send({

   where: pushQuery, // Set our Installation query
data: {
  alert: "Status Change: " + statusText
}
  }, {
success: function() {
},
error: function(error) {
  throw "Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
}
  });
});
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: After changing the status in the submission class, I'm not getting the push notification sent to users specific phone.

Comment: Can you post the complete cloud code functions? The one you pasted above wouldn't work anyways or you forgot to paste the complete afterSave for the submission. Have you tried sending a push from the dashboard to that device and checked that it works and is set up correctly?

Comment: @BjörnKaiser Not sure what you mean?  I have tested it from the dashboard and it works fine and I've tested it from the cloud code with it sending a push notification perfectly after the statusText changes but when I do that, it sends to all registered devices which is why I'm trying to target a specific one. [link] (https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions)